# Mandelbrot set in Python

Tags: python, mandelbrot

I have a problem. I'm doing a task for my lessons and I'm doing my best, but the teachers clues does not seem to help and I need to look for the problem myself facing the problem.

To begin with, I had to translate that task from my native language to english. So because of that there may be some misunderstandings as it was hard to explain it from mathematical point of view.

"There is a Mandelbrot set which is created by points defined on surface by complex numbers so as following recurrence equation does not go to infinity:

{ z0 = 0  //  zn+1 = zn^2 + c

You have to make two-dimensional array T with a size of 600x600. Each element from that array T[k][l] will represent a complex number ckl = (−2 + k * 0.005, (−1.5 + l * 0.005)ˆi). Next for each of element from T[k][l] calculate first n_max = 100 numbers from series and save that value as n, for |zn| > 2."

Yea that was painful. I googled a lot about that but I could not use all other Python scripts to solve that task. I ended up using this: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45377971/simple-mandelbrot-set-in-python), and made this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


k = 600
l = 600

T = [0][0]


for i in range(k):
    for j in range(k):
        z = 0 + 0j
        c = complex(-2 + i * 0.005, -1.5 + j * 0.005)
        for g in range(100):
            z = z * z + c
            if abs(z) > 2.0:
                T = i
                break


plt.figure(dpi=200)
plt.imshow(T, cmap="hot")
plt.show()
```

And it is really bad, I really don't understand this. Plus I get an error: *TypeError: Invalid shape () for image data*. I found another solution couple of weeks ago, sent it but it has to be done the way described in script. Please help.. thanks for your time in advance. If you need any other screenshots of the task, I'll provide it.

Comment: ........Gront? ?

Comment: Here: `T = [0][0]` the variable `T` is the integer `0` because the first `[0]` is a list of one integer `0` and the second one fetches the data at its `0`th index, which is the integer `0`

Comment: Then I should make it: T = [[0]*l for i in range(k)] ?